# How to query these datalists to retrieve data in no time?

Tags: java, object, arraylist

These are my sample classes on what I what to perform queries.

```
class TObject 
{
    String id;
    public String getId()
    {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id)
    {
        this.id=id;
    }
}

class TStructure
{
    TObject tObject;
    public TObject getTObject()
    {
        return tObject;
    }
    public void setTObject(TObject tObject)
    {
        this.tObject=tObject;
    }
}
class TStructureRow
{
    TStructure tStructure;
    TObject tObject;

    public TStructure getTStructure()
    {
        return tStructure;
    }
    public void setTStructure(TStructure tStructure)
    {
        this.tStructure=tStructure;
    }


    public TObject getTObject()
    {
        return tObject;
    }
    public void setTObject(TObject tObject)
    {
        this.tObject=tObject;
    }
}
```

I have created this classes for my sample xml data to query them. I have created Lists(data) for these classes to maitain the data in them. How can i query these lists to retrieve the results in less overhead.
For ex, these are queries:

1) `o<-tobject{tstructure}<-tstructure{tstructure_row})`

Meaning: for every object o, as tobject in tstructure, return tstructure_row of tstructure...this is the syntactic meaning

2) `o<-tobject{tstructure}<-tstructure{tstructure_row}::tobject{tobject | id = "XYZ"}<-tobject{tstructure}<-tstructure{structure_row}`

Meaning: for every object o, as tobject in tstructure, as tstructure in tstructurerow,tobject in tstructurerow whose id is "XYZ",for such tobject, as tobject in tstructure, as tstructure in tstructure row, return tstructurerow....this is the syntactic meaning

I have written bunch of nested for statements but I believe they are killing my processor if the data huge. I have to quickly find the dat from these lists on even complex queries like searching for  tObjects of more than one relevant type in the child tobjects of their respective structures.

Comment: It's hard to understand what those queries mean. It's also hard to understand the point of all these classes just to hold one (in the case of TObject and TStructure) or two (in the case of TStructureRow) String(s).

Comment: you can consider tobject in tstructure as root and in tstructure row as child to that tstructure..

Comment: This doesn't clarify anything. Are you aware that o<-tobject{tstructure}<-tstructure{tstructure_row}) is not a standard notation, and that you could very well be the only one to understand what it means?

Comment: This pseudo BNF is quite murky. Could you rephrase your question in clearer syntax/terminology?

Comment: o<-tobject{tstructure}<-tstructure{tstructure_row})
for every object o, as tobject in tstructure, return tstructure_row of tstructure...this is the syntatic meaning...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only wish to query based on `TObject` id, use [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) `HashMap<String,List<TStructureRow>`.Store List against the id of TObject.You can retrieve list of all `TStructureRow` corresponding to a particular `TObject` id in (theoretically)constant average time.

Comment: what if we have more fields in TObject like object name too..IF i want to retrieve TStructureRow based on TObject name?..What if more than one TObject has the same name and i want to retrieve all the TObjects based on names?

Comment: @user1119970 you can also use TObject as the key after overriding hashCode and equals method. You can find many tutorials on this topic eg. [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05273/index.html)